# How to deepcopy a fitted h2o.sklearn.H2OAutoMLRegressor object?

Tags: h2o

I'd like to deepcopy a fitted h2o.sklearn.H2OAutoMLRegressor object. I can deepcopy prior to calling fit but not after.

Using H2O version 3.44.0.3, the following results in an error for the deepcopy of the fitted model.

```
import copy
import numpy as np
import h2o
from h2o.sklearn import H2OAutoMLRegressor

print(f"H2O version: {h2o.__version__}")

X = np.random.rand(1000)
y = np.random.rand(1000)

m = H2OAutoMLRegressor(max_models=5, max_runtime_secs_per_model=30);

print(copy.deepcopy(m))

m.fit(X,y)

print(copy.deepcopy(m))
```

I cannot post the full trace because of StackOverflow code limits, but it looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 17
     13 print(copy.deepcopy(m))
     15 m.fit(X,y)
---> 17 print(copy.deepcopy(m))

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/copy.py:172, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    170                 y = x
    171             else:
--> 172                 y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    174 # If is its own copy, don't memoize.
    175 if y is not x:

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/copy.py:271, in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    269 if state is not None:
    270     if deep:
--> 271         state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    272     if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    273         y.__setstate__(state)

...

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/copy.py:231, in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo, deepcopy)
    229 memo[id(x)] = y
    230 for key, value in x.items():
--> 231     y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    232 return y

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/copy.py:172, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    170                 y = x
    171             else:
--> 172                 y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    174 # If is its own copy, don't memoize.
    175 if y is not x:

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/copy.py:265, in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    263 if deep and args:
    264     args = (deepcopy(arg, memo) for arg in args)
--> 265 y = func(*args)
    266 if deep:
    267     memo[id(x)] = y

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/copyreg.py:105, in __newobj__(cls, *args)
    104 def __newobj__(cls, *args):
--> 105     return cls.__new__(cls, *args)

TypeError: H2OResponse.__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'keyvals'
```

Comment: May I ask why you need to deepcopy the model?
In H2O-3, the python objects are just proxies to the "real" model on the Java backend, they are therefore connected objects and can't be deep-copied or serialized/pickled like a usual scikit-learn model.
We could try to support this but very few users seem to need this, and therefore it wasn't worth the effort until now.